# How to solve differential equation of form $y'+\frac{p(x)}{y}=q(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I go about solving a differential equation of the form $y'+\frac{p(x)}{y}=q(x)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least in the special case that $p(x) = q(x)$, the equation is separable.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $y$ and you will get and [Abel differential equation of the second kind](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0125.pdf) :
$$y\,y'=q(x)\,y-p(x)$$